# Minimal serial console

Tags: usb, hdmi, embedded-systems, rs-232

I have some embedded systems with RS-232 interfaces. But these days new computers with RS-232 interface seems quite rare, so I am wondering what alternatives might exist.

I know there are RS-232 to USB adapters, but I am wondering if there might exist a device that could be used without even needing a computer to plug it into.

Is there a device to which I can just hook up one USB keyboard and one monitor (through HDMI, DVI, or DisplayPort) and have it perform the function of a VT100 or similar?

I found [a single chip device](http://geoffg.net/terminal.html) similar to what I am looking for. That device has PS/2 keyboard interface and analog video output. What I am looking for is however USB keyboard input and digital video output.

Comment: Although I must admit having no experience with them, have you considered using a Rapsberry Pi, together with a RS-232 expansion board?

Answer (score 0):

There is one at Amazon [GOWE Resistive 15 Inch 4:3 Touch Screen Monitor for industrial PC serial port /R232 control touch display](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GMGKBJ0)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

There is Serial to Bluetooth adapters, easily fond by using a search engine.

And with a Raspberry Pi, Max323 chip you can make a Serial to ethernet (WiFi or wire depending on Raspberry Pi version) device or just ssh into the Raspberry and run minicom from the console.